# Why do I not use post hoc tests with a 2 x 2 factorial?

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

I know this is an obvious answer.  I am probably over thinking what I'm doing, but I cannot recall.  Does it have to do with not having enough variables to compare the various means?

Comment: I have just enough memory of college statistics to say that you are going to need to explain what your terms mean. There are just a few people on the site who are involved with the practical side of statistics. For myself, I remember only "factorial moments" which were clever, but I have no idea what 2 by 2 factorial would mean. As things stand, the question is on the way to being closed as gibberish.  

Comment: You should try http://stats.stackexchange.com/